# Insert value from three tables into an empty table

Tags: sql, db2

I need to select FirstName, LastName, deliver_date, order_id, total_price from table 1, table 2, table 3 according to id and order_id and put those into table 4.

Table 1

```
id   FirstName   LastName   
-------------------------
1    mr.xxxx     xxx   
2    mr.ssss     sss   
3    mr.yyyy     yyy
```

Table 2

```
order_id  deliver_date  id  tracking_number   
----------------------------------------------
    01    10/01/2017     1         1   
    02    10/01/2017     2         2   
    03    10/01/2017     3         3
```

Table 3

```
order_id   total_price      item qty   
-----------------------------------------------
   01      some price xx    some quantity xx   
   02      some price xx    some quantity xx   
   03      some price xx    some quantity xx
```

Table 4

```
FirstName, LastName, deliver_date, order_id, total_price
```

I try to do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO RECEIPT (CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_EMAIL, CUST_MOBILE, CUST_ADDRESS, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_POSTCODE, DELIVERY_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, CUST_ID, ORDER_ID) 
VALUES (SELECT CUSTOMER.CUST_FNAME, CUSTOMER.CUST_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUST_EMAIL, CUSTOMER.CUST_MOBILE, CUSTOMER.CUST_ADDRESS, CUSTOMER.CUST_CITY, CUSTOMER.CUST_STATE, CUSTOMER.CUST_POSTCODE , ORDERS.DELIVERY_DATE, "ORDER DETAIL".TOTAL_PRICE, ORDERS.CUST_ID, ORDERS.ORDER_ID FROM CUSTOMER, ORDERS, "ORDER DETAIL" WHERE CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = ORDERS.CUST_ID AND ORDERS.ORDER_ID = "ORDER DETAIL".ORDER_ID)
```

But I get an error :

> SQL0412N  Multiple columns are returned from a subquery that is allowed only one column.  SQLSTATE=42823

Comment: Side note: Please stop using the "implicit join" (comma-separated `FROM` clause), and switch to explicitly specifying `JOIN`s, with as many conditions as relevant in the `ON`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `INSERT` statement while selecting data from another table, you need to ***omit*** `VALUES` keyword.

So, it should be

```
   INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME>(col1, col2...)
     SELECT col1, col2...
```

Also, make sure have same number of columns with same in same sequence, otherwise, you will be inserting wrong values or your query will throw error due to mis-match data type.

Comment: @QuaziTarik please  read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235. You can also see up arrow. you need to click that to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
insert into table4 (FirstName, LastName, deliver_date, order_id, total_price)
select f1.FirstName, f1.LastName, f2.deliver_date, f2.order_id, f3.total_price 
from table1 f1
inner join table2 f2 on f1.id=f2.id 
inner join table3 f3 on f2.order_id=f3.order_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the error in " ...VALUES (**SELECT CUSTOMER.CUST_FNAME**, ... " in the first column to insert, maybe this sub-query has more than 1 row.

You must adjust this query to return 1 row only (more filters).

Anyway other form to backup your values to another new table, is selecting the exactly columns from your new table and save this query into a .csv file.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR,
    LastName VARCHAR

   ....
);

SELECT table1.FirstName, table2.LastName, ...  
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN ....
```

-- this query you must save into a csv file (if your DB engine is allowed to save to csv).

After you have the file ready, you must load again in the new table.